# Distinct involving correlated subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I ran into this issue in our production database and took some time to recreate it using newly created tables. I realize these queries could be written a different way, but I am just trying to figure out why this way specifically doesn't work seeing as this sort of code is riddled all throughout our production database.

Here are my creates/inserts:

```
create table Testing
(
    Code varchar2(50),
    EffTerm varchar2(50),
    Value varchar2(50)
);

create table Testing2
(
    Code varchar2(50),
    Term varchar2(50)
);

insert into Testing
values('CA',100,1);
insert into Testing
values('CA',200,2);
insert into Testing
values('CB',100,3);
insert into Testing
values('CC',100,4);

insert into Testing2
values('CA',300);
insert into Testing2
values('CB',300);
insert into Testing2
values('CC',300);
```

The idea is that I am trying to get the most recent row for each "Code". The table Testing2 is the one with the current history of these arbitrary codes. In order to get the most current "Value" for that code, I need to get the most recent effective term (represented here as 100,200,300).

The query most like my original problem in my production database looks like this:

```
select distinct VALUE
from Testing2
join Testing on Testing2.Code = Testing.Code
where Testing2.Term = 300
and Testing.EFFTERM = (select A.EFFTERM from
                        (select T.EFFTERM,
                                rank() over(order by T.EFFTERM desc) rowRank
                         from Testing T
                        where T.CODE = Testing.CODE
                          and T.EFFTERM <= Testing2.Term) A
                        where rowRank = 1)
order by 1;
```

The current term for this example is 300(values in Testing2 table). In order to get the effective term, it is using a window function to rank the terms descending and the biggest one is selected by wrapping it in a select statement. Running this specific code gives me an output of:

```
Value
1
2
3
4
```

My expected output is:

```
Value
2
3
4
```

**If all I do is remove the distinct from the outer most query, it gives me my expected output.**

After some more testing, I think it has something to do with the window function and the fact that the correlated subquery is an extra level down.

For example:

This code works perfectly fine

```
select distinct VALUE
from Testing2
join Testing on Testing2.Code = Testing.Code
where Testing2.Term = 300
and Testing.EFFTERM = (select distinct max(T.EFFTERM) over() EFFTERM
                         from Testing T
                        where T.CODE = Testing.CODE
                          and T.EFFTERM <= Testing2.Term)
order by 1;
```

But the second I wrap the subquery in another select like this:

```
select distinct VALUE
from Testing2
join Testing on Testing2.Code = Testing.Code
where Testing2.Term = 300
and Testing.EFFTERM = (select A.effterm from
                       (select distinct max(T.EFFTERM) over() EFFTERM
                         from Testing T
                        where T.CODE = Testing.CODE
                          and T.EFFTERM <= Testing2.Term) A)
order by 1;
```

It is back to giving me the output of 1,2,3,4.
And of course, if all I do is remove the distinct from the outer most query, it works fine.

**EDIT:** Just in case it matters, I am running Oracle 12c

Comment: so, testing2 always **only** has the most updated / effective?

Comment: Hm.. don't have a play time Oracle DB on hand, but I'm unable to recreate this in SQL Server.  It shouldn't make a difference, so that's curious.

Comment: @scisimon the data that I was working with was courses at a university. testing2 is like the table that says a course was created for Code = 'CA' in term ='300'. The data I need is in the table with the generic course information(like which college it belongs to). which is the table called "Testing". That data is effective dated because they don't want to store all of that info on every section created.

Answer (score 0):

So I think you are using a "feature" when if you don't have an ORDER BY in the windowing function it uses "natural order" which is the order they were inserted into the table *in some cases*.

This is not advisable.  The reason why it stops working with a sub-query is because there is no natural order for in memory results.  The order will be random.

> IN FACT the natural order can be random (especially if the table spans disks or servers or shards or whatever -- you are relying on the hardware to have an order.  Hardware can be complex.)

What you really want here is a real order.  Have a Timestamp column that gets set as a default on insert.  Then you always know when it was inserted and you can order by that column.

Comment: But I do have an order by in the first query's window function. I did it multiple ways on purpose to test it.

Comment: Quoting directly from the first paragraph of my question: "I am just trying to figure out why this way specifically doesn't work"
Why does the query only work when you remove the distinct? How could removing a distinct in an outer query change what the subquery returns?